# trouble with setting different html nodes with the same jQuery object

Tags: jquery

I am using `jQuery 1.9.0`, and my html is:

```
<div id='div1'>    
</div>
<div id='div2'>
</div>
```

my js:

```
var input = $("<input type='text'>");
$('#div1').html(input);
$('#div2').html(input);
```

my understanding of this code is

> input is a jQuery object, and I can set div1 and div2 with it separately just like I can assign one variable's value to many other variables in programming languages.

based on this understanding, what I expect is:

```
<div id='div1'>
    <input type="text">
</div>
<div id='div2'>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

but I get:

```
<div id='div1'>
</div>
<div id='div2'>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

if I just call `$('#div1').html(input);`, `div1` would have `input` element.
why does `div1`'s `input` element disappear after calling `$('#div2').html(input);`?

I know how to bypass this problem, but I am eager to know the reason of this behavior.

thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I appreciate all the guys who answered this problem sincerely, and I have voted up every answer. I have a clue to this issue now, but I am still wondering why different nodes (`div1` and `div2`) can not reference to the same object. In `C` language, different variables can reference to the same memory address. what's the difference between these two `reference`?

Comment: You have to use `.append()` and not `.html()` because `input` is a jQuery object and not HTML.

Comment: You only created one element.. So unless you clone it, it will only relocate the element to the last place you moved it

Comment: you are right, `input` is a jQuery object rather than HTML object, I have edited it. thanks :)

Comment: if you use html() then it will replace all the inside content and new thing as html .

Comment: Updated the title to reflect the behaviour you're seeing :)

Comment: I indeed want to replace content inside the divs, so `html()` is exact what I want. I have revised the misunderstanding text, which misleads you guys to think I need `append()`. thank you for your advice anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom line is that the DOM doesn't automatically clone your elements when you attach them somewhere on the page. This is not jQuery specific.

Because `input` keeps referencing the same element, attaching `input` to another element later on will detach it from the previous location, thus `input` keeps moving around in the DOM.

This is why you have to clone the element before you attach it :)

Comment: Hi Jack, thank you very much! However, I still can not understand jQuery object's `reference` very well, and I have updated the question. If you can explain it for me, I'll appreciate it sincerely!

Comment: @Brian an object in the Dom can only have one parent element and having this behaviour makes certain operations easier to write.

Comment: can I say that `div1` and `div2` can share the same `input` technically, but jQuery avoids it so that it's easier to do these certain operations?

Comment: @Brian no, they can't share the same input because that would mean two parents. This is not jQuery specific either, it's how Dom works :)

Answer (score 4):

Clone it, to work around the referencing problem (added more details below) :)

```
var input = $("<input type='text'>");
$('#div1').html(input.clone());
$('#div2').html(input.clone());
```

The reason this is happening is because input is a jQuery object. Think of it as a reference. The first time you use input, `#div1` consumes it, but then the reference is still in memory and when you add it to `#div2` it reconsumes it.

Comment: I said I know how to bypass it, but I want to know the reason of this behavior.

Comment: Hi Brian! Answer updated to explain a bit more about what is happening :) Please accept if you feel it answers your question!

Comment: Hi Dean, thank you very much! However, I still can not understand jQuery object's `reference` very well, and I have updated the question. If you can explain it for me, I'll appreciate it sincerely!

Comment: Hi Brian. I can't explain it any better than html() is a consumption operation. So if you run it twice on the same object only the most recent operation will work. The first html() call consumes it, b ut then the second html() operation "reconsumes" it and steals it from the first.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. `input` may belong to a particular node only in DOM.Same node cannot have  both `div1` and `div2`  as parents.Instead create a copy of `input` to append it to some other node

```
var input = $("<input type='text'>");

$(input).clone().appendTo('#div1');
$(input).clone().appendTo('#div2');
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look on this page? http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks

I guess this is something related to the JS's garbage collector mechanism.